# For coding strategy, is it possible to use dropdown settings to automatically change the status of the checkbox in Tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to create a strategy with different mode in it, so whenever I select the mode, it will automatically change the settings of the strategy, is that possible? In the following code, I want to make a dropbox with two modes user can choose. In this case, when the user picked, I intend to make the code automatically determine the default boolean of the textbox checkbox status.

```
mode = input(title = "Testing Mode",   defval = "mode1", options = ["mode1", "mode2"])

bool default = false

if mode == "mode1"
    default := false
else 
    default := true


check = input(default, title = "TEST")

test := check
```

But I got the following error, how can I fix it? Or is it possible to do so?

Line XX: Cannot call 'input' with 'defval'=bool. The argument should be of type: const bool;

==========================================================================

I tried to change the code as follow with no errors but the problem is there are two checkbox now and whenever I change the mode, the checkbox settings stay the same:

```
mode = input(title = "Testing Mode",   defval = "mode1", options = ["mode1", "mode2"])

bool default = false

if mode == "mode1"
    check = input(false, title = "TEST")
else 
    check = input(true, title = "TEST")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@vitruvius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7209631/vitruvius) is right. However focusing on your task/wish only disregarding your code, here is a working solution proposal that may help you.

```
//@version=5
// Strategy with 2 testing modes
strategy("My strategy in [mode1|mode2]")

// in case of 2 options only, one input field is sufficient for this purpose
// mode1 by default
runInMode2 = input.bool(false, "Run in testing mode2", group="Testing Mode")

// ...
// general LOGIC HERE
// ...

if runInMode2 == false
    // mode1 specific logic
    strategy.entry("mode1_str", strategy.long)
else
    // mode2 specific logic
    strategy.entry("mode2_str", strategy.long)
    enter code here
```

If you need some further customization, you need to add some more **input fields in advance**, like

```
...
check = input.bool(true, "Check TEST")
```

But as the previous answer said, you cannot add/change input fields dynamically. It is because of the execution model of pine script.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message tells you, the `defval` needs to be constant. So, you cannot do what you want.

You can either not use the `check` user input or let the user select the value without you changing its default value.

Comment: I change the coding to avoid the errors but didnt work as well..

Comment: Well, yes. There is no way to achieve what you want to do.